# Naming input of form html

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I could understand that this question is a bit silly but I was really asking myself...
What is the right naming for the entries in a form?
In my current form, I have this kind of naming that corresponds exactly to the name of the columns in the database :

```
<input type="text" name="nom" placeholder="Nom de la séance">
        <input type="number" name="duree" placeholder="Durée de la séance">
        <input type="number" name="kilometre" placeholder="Kilomètre total de la séance">

        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h3>Emplacement où se déroulera la séance : </h3>
        <input type="file" name="image_emplacement" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg">
        <input type="url" name="lien_emplacement" placeholder="https://www.example.com">
        <label for="localisation-seance">Choisir le niveau de la séance :</label>
        <select name="localisation" id="localisation-seance">
            @foreach($localisations as $localisation)
            <option value="{{$localisation->localisation_id}}">{{$localisation->numero_commune}} - {{$localisation->commune}} ({{$localisation->pays}})</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
```

As you can see, I use `xxx_xxx` directly in my naming (which normally should be used to separate words in sql)

UPDATE to my question :

Why I prefer to give directly the name of the column of my database because I use the mass-assignment of Laravel so I can write less code. But if it's not a good practice, I don't really see the use of the mass-assignment

I also give the primary identifiers to simplify my life and make the code less complex but I have the impression that giving the names of the columns in my database in 'plain text' is not a good thing at all...

This would help me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking is just a matter of preference. There is nothing wrong with your approach. Personally that is what I do. But again, it all comes down to what you prefer.

Answer (score -1):

`q` means query that can relate to any column name like `name`, `keyword`, or anything that is in the database. it's not a columns name in the database also. You have given a right name to do less code.  if you are worried about security then you should try to follow the instructions to prevent SQL injection.

Sql Inject: [https://www.imperva.com/learn/application-security/sql-injection-sqli/#:~:text=SQL%20injection%2C%20also%20known%20as,lists%20or%20private%20customer%20details](https://www.imperva.com/learn/application-security/sql-injection-sqli/#:%7E:text=SQL%20injection%2C%20also%20known%20as,lists%20or%20private%20customer%20details).

Comment: Thanks for the answer first...
I'm not worried about sql injections or other attacks because laravel has the ability to handle everything with different methods. I was just wondering if it was 'serious' to give to the user, the name of my database columns directly in plain.

Comment: you don't have to worry about column names then in case you don't have any secret key or something that can really be targeted to bypass the author any third party information

Comment: Is there any reason of negative marking?

Comment: I think because this not fully answer to the question i think